# QueryDSL: extract Table name from Predicate (BooleanExpression) object

Tags: java, reflection, querydsl

A method is dynamically building a list of `Predicate`s that is later passed to a database service object. In order to create table joins based on the predicate list I need to determine the underlying generated class Q* of each predicate. Calling `getType()` or `getClass()` on the Predicate doesn't help.

This is how I build the predicates:

```
Class<?> tableClazz = Class.forName("foo.bar.database.model.Q"+ WordUtils.capitalize(tableName));
Object tableObj = tableClazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(tableName +"1000");
Field colField = tableClazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
Object colObj = colField.get(tableObj);
// method name is one of eq, ne, like...
Method m = colObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, classParam );
return (Predicate) m.invoke(colObj, operand);
```

The query building code:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query = query.from(company);
for(Predicate p : predicates){
   // if there's at least one predicat with the underlying db class Foo:
   query = query.join(company.foos, new QFoo());
   break;
}
List<Object[]> rows = query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])).listDistinct(company.id);
```

Comment: Which Querydsl module are you using, JPA, SQL or something else?

Comment: I'm using the JPA. The generated Q* classes extend com.mysema.query.types.path.EntityPathBase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the generated Q-types for dynamic Expression creation. You can use dynamic paths instead http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.9.0/reference/html/ch03.html#d0e1379

In your case something like this

```
Class<?> entityType = Class.forName(...)
PathBuilder entityPath = new PathBuilder(entityType, "entity");
PathBuilder relation = entityPath.get("relation");
Predicate predicate = relation.get...(...).eq(...)
```

For Path extraction use this class http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.9.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/PathExtractor.html

`PathExtactor` extracts the first path out of a given `Expression`

Comment: That is a good tip  and I will switch to using PathBuilder. However my problem remains - how to find out later which table to use in the JPAQuery.from(X).leftJoin(...)?

Comment: In JPA you don't really join table to table, but class to class, so your remaining problem seems to be how to do the table to class mapping. I'd go over all the entity types of the JPA metamodel and create a table to entity map from that.

Comment: I think you put me on the right track with the PathExtractor. I still have trouble converting my java reflection code to your PathBuilder version. I've just created a new question on it, hopefully you find time to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273542/querydsl-generate-predicate-from-pathbuilder