# QueryDSL: generate Predicate from PathBuilder

Tags: querydsl

How to replace the following method that uses the generated Q* class and java reflexion with a PathBuilder?

```
// member vars:
T operand;  // can be a BigDecimal or a String
String tableName;
String fieldName;
String methodName;

public Predicate asPredicate()
{
   Class<?> tableClazz = Class.forName("foo.bar.database.model.Q"+ WordUtils.capitalize(tableName));
   Object tableObj = tableClazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(tableName +"1000");
   Field colField = tableClazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
   Object colObj = colField.get(tableObj);

   Class classParam = Object.class;
   if(methodName.matches(".*like"){
     classParam = String.class;
   }
   // method name is one of eq, ne, like...
   Method m = colObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, classParam );
   return (Predicate) m.invoke(colObj, operand);
}
```

this works well but I was advised to use PathBuilder instead in an answer to my other question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269845/querydsl-extract-table-name-from-predicate-booleanexpression-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269845/querydsl-extract-table-name-from-predicate-booleanexpression-object#15270675)) which would also remove the awkward newInstance(tableName +"1000").

```
PathBuilder<?> entityPath = new PathBuilder("foo.bar.database.model.Q"+ WordUtils.capitalize(tableName), "entity"); // what does the second param stand for?
PathBuilder relation = entityPath.get(fieldName);
// ???
```

two problems:
1) I can call eq() or ne() on relation now but not like(), notLike()
2) how do I get colObj so that I can use java reflection colObj.getClass().getMethod(...)

**solution:**
Thanks to Timo's answer I have ditched the reflexion altogether except for the two instanceof conditions and use this code now:

```
tableClazz = Class.forName("foo.bar.database.model."+ WordUtils.capitalize(tableName));
PathBuilder<?> entityPath = new PathBuilder(tableClazz, tableName +"1000");
Predicate predicate = null;

if(operand instanceof String){
   StringPath path = entityPath.getString(fieldName);
   switch(type){
       case EQ:
          predicate = path.eq((String) operand);
       case CONTAINS:
          predicate = path.like("%" + operand +"%");
          break;
      // snip BEGINS WITH, ENDS WITH
    }
}else if(operand instanceof BigDecimal){
    assert(type.equals(Type.EQ));
    NumberPath<BigDecimal> path = entityPath.getNumber(fieldName, BigDecimal.class);
    predicate = path.eq((BigDecimal) operand);
}
if(negation){
  return predicate.not();
}
return predicate;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use it like this

```
// entityClass is the entity type, not the Q-type
Class<?> entityClass = Class.forName(...)
// "entity" is the variable name of the path
PathBuilder<?> entityPath = new PathBuilder(entityClass, "entity"); 
// use getString to get a String path
Predicate predicate = entityPath.getString("property").like("a%");
```